# Bluetooth in a ROS package

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm new in the ROS world. I just wanna know how I can use Bluetooth in a ROS package.
I added Bluetooth libraries in the source file by:

```
#include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>
#include <bluetooth/hci.h>
#include <bluetooth/hci_lib.h>
```

and then I tried to retrieve the resource number to open the socket by:

```
dev_id = hci_get_route(NULL);
sock = hci_open_dev( dev_id );
```

but when I try to build this package I got errors saying:

> undefined reference to `hci_get_route'

> undefined reference to `hci_open_dev'

so this means the Bluetooth library is still not included. How I can add this?
Any help will be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247959/bluetooth-in-a-ros-package/) by [farhansajjad](https://answers.ros.org/users/28328/farhansajjad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2016-11-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're including the right headers, but you also need to tell the compiler to link against the bluetooth library.

In CMake, you can link against libraries with the target_link_libraries command:

```
target_link_libraries(my_target bluetooth)
```

(you'll need to replace `my_target` with the name of your target)

This is the equivalent of passing `-lbluetooth` to the compiler when building with gcc manually.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2